# C# - adding data custom checks to the compiling process

Tags: c#, compilation

Context: a simple base class which holds a name and a couple methods.

```
public abstract class BaseElement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract object GetDescription();

    public abstract void DoStuff();
}
```

A developer could subclass BaseElement, he will have to implement `GetDescription()` and `DoStuff()`, but can completely forget to assign a value to the `Name` property.

A simple solution would be to change the class this way:

```
public abstract class BaseElement
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public abstract object GetDescription();

    public abstract void DoStuff();

    private BaseElement()
    {
    }

    public BaseElement(string name)
    {
            Name = name;
    }
}
```

So, this way when you subclass you are forced to assign a name.
Still, you can always go as far as to use `null` or `""`.

Ok, then I can add a parameter check into the ctor and throw the relative exception, but...you'll discover the mistake only at run time, after you try to use the derived class.

So, the question: is it possible to add compilation-time rules to instruct the compiler to check for variables possible values, so that the problem is discovered at compile time and not at run time?

Comment: BTW, I know it's a bit far-fetched and, in all honesty, I wouldn't want to be the on team tasked with implementing such feature...

Comment: Throwing an exception and documenting it saying "it must not be null" is the cleanest way. You cannot guarantee that something won't be null because it could come from IO, algorithms or even be set by the reflection API.

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?

```
  public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            private set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    _name = value;
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Exception");
                }
            }
        }
```